# Disable keyword highlighting in lstset

Tags: listings

I have the following lstset defined for my listings

```
\lstset{
    numbers=left,                
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    tabsize=4,
    rulecolor=,
    language=java,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=true,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
}
```

However, the issue is that when I create some java code in a listings, the keywords, such as private, boolean, return etc are hightlighted in bold. I do not want this. Is it possible to disable the bold keyword highlighting?

Comment: I think adding the key/value parameter `keywordstyle=<your keyword style>` to your `\lstset` might help, e.g., `keywordstyle=\ttfamily`. `=)`

Comment: @Paulo Cereda: why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Gonzalo: I wasn't sure if my suggestion would help the OP. Now that you encouraged me, I expanded my comment to a proper answer. Thanks.

Comment: +1: not directly related to your question but your `prebreak` with `ensuremath` really helped me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a key/value parameter named `keywordstyle=<value>` in which you can redefine the keyword style.

The default settings are: keywords are typeset **bold** and comments in *italic shape*. Adding `keywordstyle=\ttfamily` to `\lstset` will redefine it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\lstset{
    numbers=left,                
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    tabsize=4,
    rulecolor=,
    language=java,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        upquote=true,
        aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
        columns=fixed,
        showstringspaces=false,
        extendedchars=true,
        breaklines=true,
        prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        frame=single,
        showtabs=false,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
public class HelloWorld {

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Hello world]

Hope it helps. `=)`

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Paulo's answer of changing the style of keywords to be identical to the surrounding text, you can also eliminate the set of recognised keywords by adding `keywords={}` after the language specification.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\lstset{
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    columns=fixed, frame=single, rulecolor=, aboveskip=1.5\baselineskip,
    showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false, tabsize=4, extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true, prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    language=java,
    upquote=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize, identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywords={}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
public class HelloWorld {
    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Code listing with keywords set to null]

Comment: This actually worked better for me than `keywordstyle=\ttfamily` because with this the keywords were still appearing slightly different (they seemed less bold than the normal code instead), while with `keywords={}` they were all the same as I required.

Comment: @jbx: Interesting. Thanks for reporting back how it worked. I wouldn't have expected there to still be a difference, especially given the image posted in Paulo's answer. Perhaps the non-keywords are being displayed in a typeface other than just `\ttfamily` (perhaps in a different size).

Comment: Yes, the difference is small, but noticable. In my case I didn't have the `identifierstyle=\ttfamily` though.